# Page wont redirect properly if folder name contains a dot

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In order to renew my SSL certificate I'm required to create a folder like `https://example.com/.well-known/pki-validation/` and put a file in there so that it's accessible. I did so but as I try to access the file I get an error that says the page is not redirecting properly. How can I fix this?

I tried the `.htaccess` below but it's not working:

```
Redirect 301 /~mysite/.well-known/pki-validation https://www.example.com/.well-known/pki-validation

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+).html$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/?$ index.php?s=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ index\.php\?s=([^\s]*)
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/?$ %1?%2%3 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I am confused ... why do you want to redirect requests to that file? I would expect that you actually want to _prevent_ any redirection or rewriting of those requests, so that you want to implement an exception?

Comment: And also: why `/~mysite/`? Where does that come from in your example?

Comment: mysite is the name of the folder inside the server. I tried by changing the htaccess like this because it didnt work anyway before that.

Comment: Just exclude requests starting with that folder from any rewriting, https://serverfault.com/a/836119

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *prevent* any requests to `/.well-known/pki-validation/` from being redirected (by the directives that occur later in the file).

The files in this directory must be directly accessible at the **HTTP** URL stated, with no redirection.

For example, at the *top* of the root `.htaccess` file, immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive:

```
# Prevent requests to "/.well-known/pki-validation/...." being processed
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/pki-validation/ - [L]
```

---

> ```
> Redirect 301 /~mysite/.well-known/pki-validation https://www.example.com/.well-known/pki-validation
> ```

Not sure what you are trying to do here, but this directive should be removed. `~mysite` looks like an [Apache per-user directory](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_userdir.html), but if you are using a "per-user directory" then requests to this directory/file will fail and the SSL cert will not be renewed.

`Redirect` is also a mod_alias directive and consequently runs *after* the existing mod_rewrite directives, despite it appearing first in the config file.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem. Im still to get a hold of the redirection rules. Its all greek to me.